# Java execute debian terminal command with "|"

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command, execute

I am experiencing a really confusing issue about sending commands to terminal via Java. 
I have exactly this code:

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"useradd", server, "-p", pass, "-d",     "/home/dakadocp/servers/" + server, "-s", "/bin/false"});
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"echo", server + ":" + pass, "|", "chpasswd"});
```

The first command is this one "useradd user -p password -d /home/ftp/test/ -s /bin/false" and the second one should be this echo username:new_password | chpasswd, the first command works without any problem and creates the user which I define by the "server" variable, but when I try to execute the second command to change users pass this command probably never happen, output is null and the password is not changed, but when I type this command directly to the terminal it works perfectly so this is just Java issue.

I think the problem is in the character "|", before I tried also some command with "|" and its behavior was the same as with this command. What I am doing wrongly ?

Thanks.
Welite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` is a shell feature, and requires a shell to run. The trivial fix is to run a shell:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", "echo something | chpasswd" });
```

However, java is more than capable of writing to a process with needing a shell or echo. The better way is to just run `chpasswd` by itself and writing the string to it:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "chpasswd" });
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
writer.println("foo:bar");
writer.close();
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, I have used the second solution and it is working pretty well!